# how to write if condition in javascript , if 1 it should show granted if 0 it should show denied

Tags: javascript, freeboard

I'm using freeboard. I cloud platform where I'm adding my API and getting results in charts. I have an API which gives the values 1 and 0 but I need to show granted and denied instead of 1 and 0. There is an option to write is in the data sources like below

```
return datasources["rfid access"] + 3 // output coming 4
```

like that i need to show granted if rfid access result is 1 and denied for 0

Comment: `return Boolean(datasources["rfid access"]) ? 'granted' : 'denied'` should do.

Comment: im getting values 1 and 0 . it should show granted or denied

Comment: Check the edited comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple logic like this:

```
if(APIval === 0){
    return 'denied';
}
else{
    return 'granted';
}
```

Or you can use a conscise version of it:

```
return APIval===0 ? 'denied' : 'granted';
```